# select rows if order # not in 3rd table

Tags: sql, db2

In the below, I am trying to select   at the, that the data selected in the first part, should not exist in the Invoice table. we want non invoiced.

```
# part 1   
CREATE VIEW Stock.CLSPAYB2 AS 
SELECT T02.OHCOM#, T02.oHPTTC, T02.oHSLR#, T01.OTTRT, T01.OTORD#, T02.ohord#, T01.OTTRND, T02.oHORDT, T02.oHordd, T02.ohttn$, t02.OHHLDC, T01.OTUSRN, T01.OTTRNC 
FROM Sales.OETRANOT T01 INNER JOIN Stock.OEORHDOH T02    
ON 
     T01.OTCOM# = T02.oHCOM# 
AND  
     T01.OTORD# = T02.oHORD# 
WHERE          
     T01.OTTRNC IN ('BCS') 
AND 
     t02.ohordd >= 20150101  

# Part 2. Here is the issue:  

AND t02.ohord#      
NOT IN 
    (
     SELECT * FROM
     Stock.OEINHDIH t03 
     WHERE t02.ohord# = t03.IHORD#
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want either `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS`, but you've mixed the syntax for the two.  Just use:

```
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM Stock.OEINHDIH t03 
            WHERE t02.ohord# = t03.IHORD#
           )
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
t02.ohord# NOT IN (SELECT t03.IHORD# FROM Stock.OEINHDIH t03)
```